# HTML Table Filter Generator doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, filter, html-table

Anybody tried out this free filter generator before? I really don't understand why this is not working at all. The JS file is in the right directory. I followed the example exactly but the filters are not showing at all. Any clues? Here is the link to the tool http://tablefilter.free.fr/

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="TableFilter/tablefilter.js"></script>  
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">            
    var tf = setFilterGrid("table1");
    </script> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>



<table id="table1" cellspacing="0" class="mytable filterable" >  
    <caption>WORLD INTERNET USAGE AND POPULATION STATISTICS</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>World Regions</th>
        <th>Population ( 2007 Est.)</th>
        <th>Population % of World</th>
        <th>% Population ( Penetration )</th>
        <th>Usage % of World</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Africa</td>
        <td>933,448,292</td>
        <td>14.2 %</td>
        <td>3.5 %</td>
        <td>3.0 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Asia</td>
        <td>3,712,527,624</td>
        <td>56.5 %</td>
        <td>10.5 %</td>
        <td>35.6 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Europe</td>
        <td>809,624,686</td>
        <td>12.3 %</td>
        <td>38.6 %</td>
        <td>28.6 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Middle East</td>
        <td>193,452,727</td>
        <td>2.9 %</td>
        <td>10.0 %</td>
        <td>1.8 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>North America</td>
        <td>334,538,018</td>
        <td>5.1 %</td>
        <td>69.4 %</td>
        <td>21.2 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Latin America / Caribbean</td>
        <td>556,606,627</td>
        <td>8.5 %</td>
        <td>16.0 %</td>
        <td>8.1 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Oceania / Australia</td>
        <td>34,468,443</td>
        <td>0.5 %</td>
        <td>53.5 %</td>
        <td>1.7 %</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move your script tags to just above the `</body>` so that it reads `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">var tf = setFilterGrid("table1");</script></body>`

Comment: Still the same. Just the table shows up. No filters.

Comment: it works!! I don't know that's how JS is placed. In the website, it says to put it in the head section.

Comment: The script has to wait for the DOM to load. The other way of doing it is to add an `onload` listener to the body element.

Comment: I've added my comment as the answer.

Comment: Thanks. However, I still don't quite understand this. Care to explain more on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your script tags to just above the `</body>` so that it reads

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var tf = setFilterGrid("table1");
  </script>
</body>
```

This is because the DOM/page elements need to load so that the script has something to work on.

The alternative would be to keep the `<script>` tags where they are but place an `onload` listener to `body`. If you read code you might have seen something like this:

```
<body onload="init()">
```

This says that the function `init` should be executed once the `<body>` (and by implication, the elements it contains) has loaded. So you might have something like this instead:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function init() {
    var tf = setFilterGrid("table1");
  }
</script>
```

If you were to use jQuery, this is solved a different way by adding a [`ready` listener to `document`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to check whether the DOM has loaded:

Either...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  // your code here
});
```

... or its shortcut:

```
jQuery(function () {
  // your code here
});
```

Hope that helps.